# How to craft a more elegant implementation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've made an interface for my students where they click an image and hear the description pronounced via text-to-speech, and the text description appears in a div.

Currently I'm calling the text from the image because the `onclick` event for the speech only works if it's on the div, and since it's a (this) event I don't understand how to combine the two.

*First*, is it possible, or "better" - to have a single click on the div trigger both functions, rather than splitting them between the div and the image as I've done? This is the only way I could figure out how to get it all working. So that's the first thing.

*Second*, I'm re-stating this code every time

```
jQuery(this).articulate('speak')" data-articulate-append=
```

How can I make this more economical? In reality I have hundreds of items, and there are a bunch more settings in between the jQuery and data-articulate. I've shortened it for this post but in reality it's much longer and repeated hundreds of times.

*Last*, is it possible to draw the content for the `innerHTML` from the `data-articulate-append` part of the TTS command, since it's the same in every case?

Many thanks, I've spent quite a while constructing what I have so far as I'm new to JS. I'm learning and I've tried to answer these questions myself but it's not yet within my skillset, and sorry if I'm not using all correct terminology in my post. I'm including a stripped-down version of the page here, with just the essentials. Any input is greatly appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://www.clients.brettcolephotography.com/test/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.clients.brettcolephotography.com/test/articulate.min.js"></script>
        <link href="http://www.clients.brettcolephotography.com/test/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
<div onclick="jQuery(this).articulate('speak')" data-articulate-append="elephant">
<img onclick="elephant()" src="http://www.clients.brettcolephotography.com/test/01.jpg">
</div>
<div onclick="jQuery(this).articulate('speak')" data-articulate-append="camel">
<img onclick="camel()"  src="http://www.clients.brettcolephotography.com/test/02.jpg">
</div>
<div onclick="jQuery(this).articulate('speak')" data-articulate-append="bear">
<img onclick="bear()"  src="http://www.clients.brettcolephotography.com/test/03.jpg">
</div>
        </div>
        <div id="word">
        </div>
        <script>
            function elephant() {
                document.getElementById("word").innerHTML ="elephant";
        }
            function camel() {
                document.getElementById("word").innerHTML ="camel";
        }
            function bear() {
                document.getElementById("word").innerHTML ="bear";
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: #1) What single question are you asking?  #2) If you asked your students to give you an "elegant" solution to something, would you expect them to know what you mean by *elegant*?  "Elegant" is not an easily quantifiable value.

Comment: Economical, in terms of code. Not more verbose and complicated than necessary. I think the way I've done it is more complicated and verbose than necessary. Re: my questions, there are three. I will put them in italics. Thanks.

Comment: If there are three questions, then you should post three separate questions.  As doing otherwise makes this question too broad, within the scope of questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'm still learning. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @thankyou I believe I was able to simplify your code in my answer and answer all of the questions. Inline event handlers are very annoying to work with, so separating it a different function makes it a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by:

Giving each div a class, for my example its `speak`. Then add an eventlistener for `speak` elements. Then in that event listener, you can run multiple functions. You can also get rid of the image's onclick handler.

```
<div class="speak" data-articulate-append="elephant"><img src="http://www.clients.brettcolephotography.com/test/01.jpg"></div>
<div class="speak" data-articulate-append="camel"><img src="http://www.clients.brettcolephotography.com/test/02.jpg"></div>
<div class="speak" data-articulate-append="bear"><img src="http://www.clients.brettcolephotography.com/test/03.jpg"></div>  
      

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".speak").on("click",function(){
        $(this).articulate('speak');
        $("#word").html($(this).data("articulate-append"));
    });
});
```

Comment: This is fantastic, and I understand how it works now. Can't wait to apply it to other projects. Thanks.

Comment: @thankyou, no problem. Now looking into the future, if you decide that you want to use IDs instead of a class, make sure EACH id is different on the SAME page. No two elements can have the same ID. This is a common problem people have without realizing it.

Comment: Can I put all of these divs inside one parent div with the speak class and then use .nextAll().addClass or a similar approach to avoid having to restate the class for every div? I tried modifying $(".speak") with this but no success

Comment: @thankyou, you should be able to replace ‘.speak’ with ‘[data-articulate-append]’ and it will work for all elements with that data attribute. You won’t need to change any other parts of my code and you won’t need to add class=speak to the divs

Comment: Wow, that's awesome, so much more economical. Thanks again